# Call a function from parent function's parent class

Tags: php, class

Let's say, for simplicity, this is how my page is set up:

```
class TFS extends PHP_db
{
    public function execute() {
        class Dostuff {
            public static function doit() {
                return "wee";
            }
        }
    Now here I can use Dostuff:doit() successfully
    And also $this->db->functionhere() which is from the PHP_db is also successful from here

    }
}
```

I need to figure how to call `$this->db->functionhere()` from within the `doit()` function inside the Dostuff class..

I have already tried this in the Dostuff class:

```
protected $parent_object;
public function __construct( $object ) {
    $this->parent_object = $object;
 }
```

and this from the execute() function: `$dostuffclass = new Dostuff($this);`

But then when I try to use `$parent_object->db->functionhere()` it doesn't work, telling me it's not an object.

Comment: You normally do not put classes into functions. I'd say that is you major and foremost mistake. Move it out there. Apart from that I have real problems to understand what you do. However, no need to explain anything unless you have not moved the class Dostuff out of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the `$this` context to the internal `DoStuff` class as a parameter, for example:

```
class TFS extends PHP_db
{
    public function execute() {
        class Dostuff {
            public static function doit($somevar) {
                $somevar->functionhere();
                ^^^^ <-- add this
                return "wee";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The internal class `DoStuff` does not need to know anything about the `$this` context you are referring to, since you are sending a reference to an existing class instance to it as a parameter.

Comment: Hmm, this would work and I appreciate the time but I've come to the conclusion I don't actually need any of the stuff inside the `Dostuff` class, so I'm just going to remove that class and just use the functions as is, it makes more sense to me